# Вопрос с ответом в комментариях: копировать решение в свой ответ или звать модератора для преобразования коммента в в ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, неотвеченные-вопросы, комментарии

**Дано:**

Вопрос с ответом в комментах. Там же ТС пишет, что это решило проблему. По алгоритму же робота такой вопрос подлежит удалению.

Пример: [Работа с api vk(android)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442123/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-api-vkandroid)

**Вопрос:**

*Что же делать?*

1. Публиковать свой ответ с указанием на автора коммента?
2. Таки звать модератора, чтобы он переделал коммент в ответ?

**Краткий вопрос:**

Может хоть так можно медальку-то ([deputy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deputy)) за тревоги получить?

Comment: Вроде уже обсуждалось. Модераторов на всех не напасешься. Если можете — публикуйте как свой ответ. Если при этом ничего не добавляете — желательно сделать ответ общим.

Comment: Но если на сайте нехватка модераторов, то как их взрастить, если не девать им медальки нужные зарабатывать, жестко ограничивая возможности их зарабатывания? Ждать когда прибегут матершинники и их тревогой отмечать? =)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Конвертирование и редактирование комментариев?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо, раньше меня вопрос нашли. Там хороший ответ.

Comment: @Nofate: ну вот, вы лишили нескольких человек возможности поревьюить на Мете. Останутся без знаков. :)

Comment: Ну вот, ещё и минус(

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у нас и так один активный модератор, и тот постоянно где-то слоняется. Возможностей - бери-не хочу ) Кто-то вот проходил и минусом отмодерировал, например.

Answer (score 4):

Нет у модераторов способа сконвертировать комментарий в ответ.

Так что берите власть в свои руки. Скопируйте комментарий в новый ответ и отметьте его как общий.

Deputy не так уж сложно получить при творческом подходе.

Comment: Я просто пытаюсь сложить разрозненные сведения в алгоритм чёткого определения что можно "тревожить" так, чтобы и полезно было и никто не возмущался)

Comment: Похоже, надо написать конкретную пошаговую инструкцию по творческому подходу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тогда он их творчества превратится в серое ремесло, а я замучаюсь подтверждать тревоги )

Comment: Athari в главном чате писал когда-то.